# Como salvar atualizações em objeto através do form do django?

Tags: django, formulário, view, django-2.2

Tenho uma aplicação e quando eu mando os dados no form para serem atualizados funciona ( os dados são apresentados no form) mas quando eu clico em salvar a atualização ele repete os dados iniciais e não salva nada.

Segue código :

view.py

```
def Atualizar(request, id):
    atualizar = get_object_or_404(Local, id=id)
    local = FormularioLocal(instance=atualizar)
    if local.is_valid():
        local_banco = local.save(commit=False)
        local_banco.save()
        return redirect("gerenciar_local")

    form = {}
    form['local'] = local

    return render(request, "local/atualizar.html", form)
```

E o template com o intuito renderizar o form com os dados passados :

```
<h1> Atualizar <h1>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ local.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Como faço para salvar as atualizações realizadas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando um [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)?

```
# forms.py
# ...
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

# views.py
# ...    
def atualizar(request, id): 
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, id=id)
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('next_view')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django

Ou ainda melhor, utilize a [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview).

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando o ModelForm. Essa sua resposta deu certo.